# Find sids who made exactly one reservation?

Tags: sql

I write "Find sids who made exactly one reservation"query with Using group by having like this:

```
SELECT R.sid
FROM   Sailors S,
       Reserve R
WHERE  R.sid = S.sid
GROUP  BY R.sid
HAVING Count(R.sid) = 1
```

But I want to alsa find it by using (not exists) command.I write it

```
SELECT S.sid
FROM   Sailors S
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT R.sid
                   FROM   Reserve R
                   WHERE  Count(R.sid) <> 1)
```

But it has errors.How can I write it by using not exists command.

Comment: What is the PK of `Reserve`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Reserve has a primary key rid, you can write it like so:

```
Select
  s.sid
From
  Sailors s
    Inner Join
  Reserve r
    On s.sid = r.sid
Where
  Not Exists (
    Select
      'x'
    From 
      Reserve r2
    Where
      r2.sid = s.sid And
      r2.rid != r.rid
  );
```

Note, in this case you don't even need to reference the Sailors table:

```
Select
  r.sid
From
  Reserve r
Where
  Not Exists (
    Select
      'x'
    From 
      Reserve r2
    Where
      r2.sid = r.sid And
      r2.rid != r.rid
  );
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cce6c/2

Comment: thanks @Laurence.And Can I write it by not using group by/having command.

Comment: @GokhanISIK I've updated it to not use group by, but it now depends on Reserve having a primary key.

Comment: ı cant understand why you use "x".What do you mean?

Comment: In the inner query you're only testing whether a record exists that meet the criteria. It doesn't matter what values you select.

Comment: very very thanks.The lastly can you help me about writing this query by using Unique.İs it possible.I Tried but it doesn't

Comment: The only place I know that Unique is used in SQL is defining indexes and constraints.